# Concatenating a char in a recursive function in C

Tags: c, recursion, char, strcpy, strcat

Even though I have more experience with higher level languages, I am having a lot of troubles understanding how memory `allocation` and how `strings` really work in `C`.

I am trying to implement a very simple base converter that works recursively. The only thing is that it should return a `char*` instead of an `int`

Here is my code. I already tested the recursive calls and it works if I use integers. So, the problem is definitely with the string part. It gives me an infinite loop.

```
char* baseConversion(int num, int baseIn, int baseOut){

    //convert num to base ten

    int quotient = num / baseOut;

    int remainder = num % baseOut;

    char rem = (char)(((int)'0') + remainder);

    char *result = malloc(strlen(output) + 1);

    strcpy(result, rem);

    if (quotient == 0)
        return result;
    else
        return strcat(result, baseConversion(quotient, baseIn, baseOut));
}
```

Many thanks

Comment: I don't see the question anywhere...

Comment: The second argument of `strcpy` must be a null-terminated string. `rem` is a char, not a string.

Comment: Sixth line states that there is an infinite loop super cool guy ;)

Comment: True @Barmar. Let me see what can I do.

Comment: @CoolGuy: A question doesn't need to end with a question mark sign.

Comment: what is `output` in `malloc`?

Comment: a global `char[10]` variable

Comment: @What are baseIn and output?

Comment: @Luis Lavieri See my answer, son.

Comment: The algorithm does not work, even if all the coding errors are fixed.  Example,  Lets say 'num' started out as 101 in decimal and the baseout = 10.  Then the first pass would produce a 1. The first recursion would produce 0, so the result would be 1:0 (10 in printable decimal.)  When, the actual value should be 1:0:1 (101 in printable decimal).  Also, the final result would be undefined behaviour unless the variable 'output' is >= 3 in length and pre-set to all '\0'.

Comment: You are forgetting two ones produced from the recursive calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
strcpy(result, rem);
```

to:

```
result[0] = rem;
result[1] = 0;
```

This will create a single-character string containing the character in `rem`.

You also may need to fix:

```
malloc(strlen(output)+1)
```

as there's no variable named `output` in your function.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly what you are saying about then what you need is the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char * baseConversion( unsigned int x, unsigned int base )
{
    unsigned int digit;
    char *p = NULL;
    size_t n = 2;

    if ( base > 10 || base < 2 ) base = 10;

    digit = x % base;

    if ( x / base ) p = baseConversion( x / base, base );

    if ( p ) n += strlen( p );

    p = realloc( p, n );

    *( p + n  - 2 ) = digit + '0';
    *( p + n  - 1 ) = '\0';

    return p;
}   


int main(void) 
{
    unsigned int x = 255;

    char *p = baseConversion( x, 10 );

    printf( "%s\n", p );

    free( p );

    p = baseConversion( x, 8 );

    printf( "%s\n", p );

    free( p );

    p = baseConversion( x, 2 );

    printf( "%s\n", p );

    free( p );

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
255
377
11111111
```

P.S. It is funny when one answer is marked as the best but the code will be used from other answer.:)

Comment: My question was about how to correct the infinite loop. @Barmar helped me out with that. I was not asking for the proper algorithm. That is why you don't get the right answer.

Comment: @Luis Lavieri My answer is the most helpful because it shows how the program should be written correctly. It teaches how such programs should be written in C.